# Flex File reading problem

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript

i am having a problem in reading a file from Flex. The file contains a base64encoded string. when i read the file i get the length as 47856 and the decoded base64 byte array length as 34157.

When i read the same File from java i get the length as  48068 and 35733 respectively.

What is the problem?

```
 private function init():void{
        var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("Files/sample.txt");
        stream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
        var str:String = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);
        stream.close();
        str = str.replace(File.lineEnding, "\n");
        contents.text = str;
        fileName.text = file.name;
    }


public function playSound(contents:String):void{



    try{
        var byteData: ByteArray;

        byteData = new ByteArray();
        byteData.writeUTFBytes(contents);
        var dec:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
        dec.decode(contents);
        byteData = dec.toByteArray();



        Alert.show("byte Array   " + byteData.toString().length +" ::  " +contents.length);


    }
```

And this is my java code for reading the file...Whatever result i am expecting is achieved in the java side.

```
private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {  
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path)); 
        try {   
            FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel(); 
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());   

            return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();   } 
        finally {     stream.close();   
        } 
    }
```

Java Code where i am printing the length

```
byte[] decodedBase64 = new byte[byteLength];
                String speexData = null;
                try {
                    speexData =   readFile(userDir +"//" +xmlFileName);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                // System.out.println("sa " + sa);

                try{

                    decodedBase64=  Base64.decodeToByteArray(speexData);
                    System.out.println("decodednase64 length " + decodedBase64.length +" :: " +speexData.length());
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to post your java code to show what you're doing there, as well.

However, without knowing more, I could take a guess and say that when you replace the line ending, you may be removing a byte each time (if it was \r\n and you're making it \n, for example).

Comment: What happens if you remove the line where you replace the line endings?

Comment: @above: actually i got the out put i required..But still then i can't understand why such difference is there.

Comment: In your flash code, why aren't you looking at stream.bytesAvailable and byteData.bytesAvailable?